# Are plain footnotes now impossible?

Tags: org-mode

I have had `(setq org-footnote-auto-label 'plain)` in my init.el
to get footnote labels of the form[1].  But after updating to
version 9, I see this option is no longer supported?  Does
this really mean that there is no longer any way to get plain
footnotes??  (Surely there is no reason to prefer[fn:1] in documents that have no chance of containing false positives? which is true of all my documents.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true, that style of footnote no longer works. [ORG-NEWS](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/etc/ORG-NEWS) says:

> Footnotes
>
> [1]-like constructs are not valid footnotes
>
> Using `[1]` as a footnote was already discouraged in the manual, since
>   it introduced too many false-positives in many Org documents.  These
>   constructs are now unsupported.
>
> If you used `[N]` in some of your documents, consider turning them into
>   `[fn:N]`.